# What is interfering with TabIndex order on my dialog form?

Tags: .net, winforms, dialog

I'm using VS2013 on a VB.NET 4.0 Winforms project with Telerik controls (though none are in this dialog). I have a simple dialog with three static labels, two text boxes and the 'OK' and 'Cancel' buttons. I've changed the TabIndex values so that tab should flow like: tbUserName(0) -> tbPW(1) -> OK_Button(2) -> Cancel_Button(3).

In reality, the flow goes like: tbUserName(0) -> OK_Button(2) -> Cancel_Button(3) -> tbPW(1).

I initially set the TabIndexes through the Properties window. Then I used the View > Tab Order tool to set them. The Properties window shows the TapIndex as I've set them but the Tab Order tool shows the two buttons that came with the form as 0.1 and 0.2. (Which I don't understand because it's an Int32 and won't let me set TabIndex to decimal values.) I have also attempted to set the TabIndex from my code, but the behavior regarding those buttons doesn't change. It seems that they *really* want to go first.

I'm sure that I'm missing something simple, but my searches aren't finding it.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are using container controls.  Easy to see with View + Tab Order.  And to fix with that feature, click them in the order you want them.

Comment: It didn't display anything that made me think there was a container, though now that I've reset it to a higher number, I can see there's a sliver of a box behind the button. The real trick to this was that the container is there by default and easy to remain ignorant about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any kind of group in your form ?
If you design a group and then paste two textboxes, you'll get a decimal value on two texboxes TabIndex (e.g. 1.1 and 1.2)

Comment: Yes! Apparently when you tell VS to add a dialog, the default buttons are in a TableLayoutPanel. I've never noticed this before. And it has its own TabIndex property that's set to 0 (because at creation, it's the only control on the form). I was a little bit onto this before your post, but that's exactly right.